# Admin API appengine.apps.authorizedCertificates.patch returns 200 with unknown error

Tags: google-app-engine, https

When updating the certificates via the Appengine Admin API I consistently get an unknown error. I've moved to the API explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/) to rule out any other errors.

I populate all the fields (appsId, authorizedCertificatesId, updateMask, and patch body) with relevant data.

The Result is a 200 accepted, but an unknown error javascript dialog box is popped as a response. Additionally the new certificate doesn't get utilized.

Actual response

> 200 OK - Hide headers - cache-control: private content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 date: Thu, 20 Jul 2017 10:24:42 GMT server: ESF transfer-encoding: chunked vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer { "name": "apps/xxx-162220/authorizedCertificates/34643", "id": "34643", "displayName": "Try3", "domainNames": [ "xxx.de", "www.xxx.de" ], "expireTime": "2017-11-18T09:22:00Z", "certificateRawData": { "publicCertificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIFDTCCAxxx\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIEkjCCAxxx\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" }}

Is this a bug as it's in beta or is someone able to complete this successfully? The api is appengine.apps.authorizedCertificates.patch

Comment: What do you mean by "new certificate doesn't get utilized", do you see it on the list of certificates?

Comment: The patch method updates an existing certificate. Doesn't get utilized means the instance is still using the old cert.